# Session makes two files one empty one with my variables

Tags: php

hello im taking variables from $_POST and stores them in Sessions but i cant figure out why my program creates two files per $_POST och empty and one with my variables.

```
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();


$_SESSION['S_LocalIP'] = $_POST['LocalIP'];
$_SESSION['S_Computername'] = $_POST['Computername'];
$_SESSION['S_GUID'] = $_POST['GUID'];
$_SESSION['S_BaseAddress'] = $_POST['BaseAddress'];

var_dump($_POST);
session_write_close();
```

everything works like i want except i get the one empty session file aswell.

Comment: Why are you using `session_regenerate_id();`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you use `session_regenerate_id()`, use `session_regenerate_id(true)` instead to remove the old id.

The first parameter for this function is `$delete_old_session` which by default is set to `false`.

Comment: Thank you works like i want now :) i'll read up more on session_regenerate_id() function thank you!